# Linking a subdomain to a drupal "virtual path" using cPanel?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-6, dns

I've created a page at

```
/forum
```

So if I open:

```
www.mydoman.com/forum
```

Then i can see my forum. But note, there is no FOLDER "forum". When you open "/forum" a paramteer is passed to Drupal saying that you are now accessing the forum. These rules are set up by the .htacess file.

So my question is, how can I create:

forum.mydomain.com

to show the contents located at www.mydomain.com/forum ?

Comment: does forum.mydomain.com currently show the same website as mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question comes in two parts:

a) you must first set up your cPanel to permit serving pages for forum.mydomain.com from the same set of files as www.mydoman.com

This involves using a "Parked Domain" on that cPanel account (i hope your cPanel account has privs for this). You may or may not need to place a symbolic link on the server, so that the parked domain is equivalent to the original domain.

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/AddonDomains

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-the-difference-between-parked-addon-and-subdomains

b) next up you need to change your Drupal deployment to a multisite set up (i.e. create a subdirectory in sites/ with the name forum.mydomain.com and in there use a settings.php file that is identical to any you might have in default. Having done this, you should be able to set the homepage value for that site to be /forum via the variable that controls the frontpage

$conf['site_frontpage'] = "/forum";

http://drupaleasy.com/quicktips/module-development-settings-variables-settingsphp-using-conf

Answer (score 0):

This [module](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain)  will help you take a look.

Automatically creates subdomains and places content on them. There are 4 modes:

User: e.g. "Mary" and content atmary.example.com

Taxonomy: e.g. "Seattle" and content ateattle.example.com

Organic Group: e.g. "MyGroup" and content at mygroup.example.com

Content type subdomains: e.g. "News" content at news.example.com